# R indexing a function under an if else statement inside a for loop and returning correct values

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, indexing

I'm having trouble with indexing a function correctly so that it would return the correct values. The function is only applied when an `if` condition is met, and the `ifelse` statement is in a `for` loop.

I've simplified my function and dataset to make the example reproducible here - the way I wrote it currently is not very efficient, but I just want to make sure the indexing works so that I can try applying this back to my more complicated dataset, then work on optimizing later on.

First I start with some data:

```
var1 <- seq(100, 500, 100)
matrix1 <- matrix(1:12, ncol=2)
matrix2 <- matrix(c(1,2,5,6,8,9,11,12,14,15,17,20), ncol=2)
matrix3 <- matrix(seq(1,34,3), ncol=2)
list1 <- list(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3)
```

I have a function that takes in a data frame like below:

```
func1 <- function(df1) {
  data1 <- df1[,1]
  data2 <- df1[,2]
  data3 <- vector()
  data3[i] <- sum(data1, data2)
  return(data3)
}
```

And my `for` loop looks like below:

```
for (i in (1:3)) {
  vec1 <- var1
  vec2 <- diff(unlist(list1[[i]])[,1])
  df1 <- matrix()
  df1 <- cbind(vec1, vec2)
  len <- length(which(vec2<3))
  if (len>1) {
    func1(df1)
  }
  else data3 <- NA
  print(data3)
}
```

I'm trying to only apply `func1` if my `df1` passes the `length` test, and if it doesn't meet the length requirement, I want to give it an `NA` value.

When `i=1`, `len=5` and `data3=1505`; when `i=2`, `len=4` and `data3=1508`; when `i=3`, `len=0` so `data3=NA`. In short, the result I want to return from the `for` loop is `data3 = c(1505, 1508, NA)`.

However, I can't get that result now, and since individually running for `i=1` `i=2` and `i=3` works, I'm suspecting that I'm having an index issue (probably inside `func1` I suppose) but can't figure it out. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted the loop syntax a bit:

```
data3 <- vector(length = 3, mode = "numeric")
for (i in 1:3) {
  vec1 <- var1
  vec2 <- diff(unlist(list1[[i]])[,1])
  df1 <- matrix()
  df1 <- cbind(vec1, vec2)
  len <- length(which(vec2<3))
  if (len>1) {
    v <- func1(df1)
    v <- v[!is.na(v)] #when i = 2, func1 returns a vector of length 2
    data3[[i]] <- v
  }
  else {
    data3[[i]] <- NA
  }
}

data3
[1] 1505 1508   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you had a typo in your function `func1`, which should be

```
func1 <- function(df1) {
  data1 <- df1[,1]
  data2 <- df1[,2]
  data3 <- vector()
  data3 <- sum(data1, data2)
  return(data3)
}


data3 <- c()
for (i in (1:3)) {
  vec1 <- var1
  vec2 <- diff(unlist(list1[[i]])[,1])
  df1 <- matrix()
  df1 <- cbind(vec1, vec2)
  len <- length(which(vec2<3))
  if (len>1) {
    r <- func1(df1)
  }
  else r <- NA
  data3 <- c(data3,r)
}
```

After fixing that, you will get the output

```
> data3
[1] 1505 1508   NA
```

Comment: I actually think I'm getting `NA` `NA` `NA` for the output? I thought I should "save" the values of `data3` into an empty vector to export it outside of the function, which is why I initially put an `[i]` index in `data3` inside the function.

Comment: @Jennifer see my updates, then `data3` saves values from each iteration